# Generate N random polygons without overlap in a given area with PostGIS

Tags: postgis

In the same idea as with points :

```
SELECT (
  st_dump(
    ST_GeneratePoints(
      ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((1 35, 1 59, 27 59, 27 35, 1 35))',4326),
      100
    )
  )
).geom;
```

[image]

How could I generate N random polygons in PostGIS (>=3.0.0) (which don't overlap) in a given area?
(with or without choosing their number of sides, but let's start with triangles only, for the sake of simplicity).

This sounds pretty simple at first glance. I was thinking of using a convex hull around subsets of M points / or a buffer with quad_segs around single points, but I cannot figure out how to handle the "non overlapping" part of the problem in a straightforward and simple manner (i.e. without testing them all for intersections).

The best idea I came with was to make use of a Delaunay triangulation / dumping the triangle / shrinking them with a negative buffer, e.g.:

```
SELECT 
ST_Transform(
  ST_Buffer(
    ST_Transform(
      (ST_Dump(
        ST_DelaunayTriangles(
          ST_GeneratePoints(
            ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((1 35, 1 59, 27 59, 27 35, 1 35))',4326),
            100
          )
        )
      )).geom,
    3857),
  -40000), -- -40km buffer
4326)
;
```

[image]

But I cannot chose their number, and some small triangles may shrink to the point they disappear(?)

Also this won't work for let's say square or pentagons. Obviously. Unless I missed a "quadri-angulation" or "penta-angulation" meshing algorithm...

Comment: Your problem statement is a bit under-constrained.  What should these random polygons look like?  What does the containing area look like (is it always a rectangle, or an arbitrary polygon?)

Comment: How about generating a random set of N points in a rectangle, then computing the Voronoi Diagram for them?  Can then apply a negative buffer to each Voronoi cell, if desired.

Answer (score 2):

For simplicity, cluster a set of random points, and get the concave hull per cluster - no way to specify side count directly¹, but easy to generate pseudo-random Polygons:

```
SELECT
  ST_ConcaveHull(ST_Collect(geom), <F>) AS geom
FROM (
  SELECT
    aoi.<id>,
    ST_ClusterKMEANS(dmp.geom, <N>) OVER(PARTITION BY aoi.<id>) AS cid,
    dmp.geom
  FROM
    <area_of_interest> AS aoi,
    LATERAL ST_Dump(ST_GeneratePoints(geom, <S>)) AS dmp
) q
GROUP BY
  aoi.<id>, q.cid
HAVING
  COUNT(*) > 2
;
```

where

- `<N>` is the desired *Polygon* count; try `20`
- `<S>` is the *sample size* to cluster over, i.e. random point count; try `150`
- `<F>` is the factor of concavity to aim for, with `1.0` being the *convex hull*; try `0.7`

**Notes:**

- I use `ST_ConcaveHull` here, which obviously may create *concave* Polygons; the reason is that any *concavity* adds computational complexity to aerial geometries compared to strictly *convex* ones - there are a few high performance shortcuts available in common algorithms on *convex* Polygons that cannot get applied to *concave* ones
- due to the nature of the `K Means` algorithm, higher *sample sizes* of pseudo-random observations over a regular area will increase the gridding effect of its clusters; they will tend to be of equal shapes and appear regularly spaced over the area - keep `<S>` low to introduce some irregularities
- I added a `HAVING` clause to exclude invalid geometries; with decreasing ratio of `<N> : <S>` there will be clusters with less than 3 points, resulting in `LineString`s or `Point`s after creating the convex hull - keep an eye on the result set count and increase the ratio (add more `<S>` or lower `<N>`) if necessary

---

¹ You *could* extract 3 Points per cluster and polygonize them into triangles - this can only work reliably with triangles, though.

Another way would be to get the `ST_MinimumInscribedCircle` per random *Polygon*, and then create an `ST_Buffer` (or an [`ST_MakeAGon`](https://gist.github.com/geozelot/ddf88a9ae0438d7a46f176e9555ce7a1)) with the returned parameters - this would guarantee non-overlapping *Polygons* with specific side counts.

Comment: Not sure to fully understand what to set for `<id>` in your example... neither by `<area_of_interest>`: is it equivalent as `geom`?

Comment: @swiss_knight the above query is suitable to generate random polygons inside multiple AOIs (e.g. from a table) - but it requires a unique id. If you want to pass it a single AOI, simply remove the id parts.

Comment: Or simply do `... FROM VALUES (1, 'POLYGON(...)'::GEOMETRY) AS aoi(id, geom) ...` to use the one polygon in your example.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way:

- generate random points in the rectangle
- compute their Voronoi Diagram
- clip each Voronoi cell to the rectangle
- negative buffer each cell by a small amount to separate them (it might be necessary to compute a different buffer distance for each cell, as say a fraction of the radius of the Minimum Inscribed Circle).

```
SELECT 
  ST_Buffer(
    ST_Intersection(
      (ST_Dump(
        ST_VoronoiPolygons(
          ST_GeneratePoints('POLYGON((1 35, 1 59, 27 59, 27 35, 1 35))',
            100
          ))
      )).geom
    ,'POLYGON((1 35, 1 59, 27 59, 27 35, 1 35))')
  , -.2);
```

[image]